# undefined method `eager_load_namespaces' for when running sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm getting the following error when running the `sidekiq` on `rails 4.1.4`.

Here is entire error log

```
undefined method `eager_load_namespaces' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x00000002a3c788>
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/railtie.rb:6:in `<class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/railtie.rb:5:in `<module:ActiveModel>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.4/lib/active_model/railtie.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:3:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:10:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/all.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/santosh/Roorah/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/santosh/Roorah/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/santosh/Roorah/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:227:in `boot_system'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.0/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

Please do ask if any further information is required.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue? I'm also getting similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Rails to version 4.2.10 or later.

At least the method `Rails::Railtie::Configuration#eager_load_namespaces` is defined railties-4.2.10.